# SQL Server Management Tools Installation fails with registry Wow6432Node key's (default) value

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, permissions, registry, 64-bit

On Windows 7 x64, SQL Server 2014(x64) Management Tools installation fails with the following error;

```
Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
Component name:                SQL Server Management Services
Component error code:          1406
Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20140719_170948\sql_ssms_Cpu64_1.log
Error description:             Could not write value  to key \SOFTWARE.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
```

I monitored installation with `Process Monitor` and find that it is trying to write(RegSetValue) `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\(Default)` value which results in "Access Denied".

So, when i try to change that key's default value within regedit, it is not allowed too;
`Cannot edit :  Error writing the value's new contents.`.

For Wow6432Node key, i grant permissions to following users/groups; Everyone, Current Admin Account, Administrators, System but that did not help to change that default value even with regedit.

I could only think about registry corruption or some windows bug or may be some other program intervention, so, i disabled antivirus app. What might it be and how could i solve it?

Comment: I too am having this issue while installing SQL Server 2014 Express, on Windows 7 x64. Haven't been able to figure it out and changing permissions in RegEdit fixes nothing. I'm thinking about maybe also completely uninstalling Visual Studio and starting the install process over without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several things, finally, i applied the following and it worked. Restart may be required after applying it.

regdacl HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node /gga:F /ggu:F /ggs:F

Download regdacl here
http://www.heysoft.de/en/software/regtools.php?lang=EN